# coreferentiality: what is a 'reference', exactly?

Tags: terminology

I would like to understand what is meant in a grammar discussion when someone uses the word "coreferential". I understand it to mean that two or more constituents (e.g. a noun and a noun phrase) must reference the same entity, but I'm not really sure what is required for a constituent to be considered a *reference*, as distinct from a description or an ascription.

Consider:

> Jane Doe, **soprano in the church choir**, had a bad cold.
>
> Jane Doe, **a soprano in the church choir**, had a bad cold.
>
> Jane Doe, **best soprano in the church choir**, had a bad cold.
>
> Jane Doe, **the best soprano in the church choir**, had a bad cold.

Are all of the bolded phrases *coreferential* with "Jane Doe"?

Only two of them, the ones with the article, can clearly stand as the grammatical subject of the verb phrase in their sentence:

> *soprano in the church choir had a bad cold.
>
> a soprano in the church choir had a bad cold.
>
> *best soprano in the church choir had a bad cold. (marginal?)
>
> the best soprano in the church choir had a bad cold.

And of those two, only the latter, the one with the definite article, seems (to me) to yield meaning equivalent to the following:

> Jane Doe had a bad cold.

So, to be "coreferential", does the noun phrase have to point directly to the preceding noun, and to it *uniquely*, and must it also be able to stand in its place in the sentence and yield equivalent meaning when so standing, or does the noun phrase merely have to be *predicable* of the preceding noun? Just how strict is the definition of *reference*?

Comment: In *John hugged Bob, but he didn't like it*, the pronoun *he* can be coreferential with both *John* and *Bob*. It depends on the speaker's intention which is the case. Similarly it does not matter if a description like *a soprano in the church choir* does not refer to the same entity uniquely out of context. I am not certain about the other issue. If those phrases without article are analyzed with ellipsis, it is unrelated that they cannot be a subject.

Comment: Not sure what you meant by "out of context".  In "John, a swimmer, gets up early for practice", is "a swimmer" coreferential with "John"? I'm thinking no.

Comment: They are. Out of context, *a swimmer* may not uniquely refer to John, just like *he* in my example and the indefinite in the question do not uniquely refer. But coreferentiality is about the reference *in context*. In *John, a swimmer*, there is no reading under which the two do not refer to the same entity.

Comment: To be coreferential with a preceding noun, does a noun phrase have to be a grammatical *proxy* for it, as a pronoun is a proxy for the noun?  I ask because with the various NPs in my question, the NP's role as proxy seems questionable in those cases where the sentence is not grammatical when the NP is substituted for the noun.

Comment: I see reference as a matter of semantics, and I don't really see a reason to involve a syntactic constraint (i.e., to not use the notion reference for bare NPs like *soprano in the choir*). Why do you think this is relevant? Maybe it would help if you would include more details about what you're reading where coreference is used, and we can try to clarify a specific aspect, without remaining in the abstract.

Comment: I am *asking* if a syntactic constraint is relevant since most discussions of coreferentiality refer to pronouns as the prime example, as did you, and a pronoun is a proxy that can be substituted for the noun, and with such substitution the resulting statement is grammatical. So I'm just hoping to find a definition of the term that sets out the syntactic requirements a **reference** needs to satisfy, if there are any.

Comment: If you look at the [wikipedia page for coreference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coreference) there is also an example with corefering NPs. What expressions refer, exactly, will probably depend on your framework. It is possible to analyze *soprano in the choir* as a bare NP, a description of an entity that does not refer. But it is also possible to analyze it as a DP with a null head, and let it refer, and let something else account for the fact that it cannot be a subject. Pronouns are typically given as an example because the matter is so clear in that case.

Comment: I don't understand the phrase "is a predication over" there on the Wikipedia page. "over" makes no sense to me. And both of the NPs there are DPs.

Comment: “Predication over” probably just means that the second predicates something (e.g. *is a jerk*) of the referent of the first DP.

Comment: So, comparable to my "John, *a swimmer*, ..."  But the Wiki page doesn't really deal with non-DP NPs.